# Drawing Ellipse on Canvas with "negative" width/height using mouse events

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

On MouseDownEvent I set upper left corner of Ellipse I'm trying to draw.

```
public MyCircle(Point location)
    {
        ellipseObject = new Ellipse
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.Black,
            StrokeThickness = 2,
            Margin = new Thickness(location.X, location.Y, 0, 0)
        };
    }
```

Then on MouseMoveEvent I update Width and Height properties and it works fine as long as I don't move mouse above or/and to the left of my Ellipse upper left corner, in that case I'm getting exception that these properties can't be negative (which of course makes perfect sense).

```
public void Draw(Point location)
    {
        if (ellipseObject != null)
        {                
            ellipseObject.Width = location.X - ellipseObject.Margin.Left;
            ellipseObject.Height = location.Y - ellipseObject.Margin.Top;               
        }
    }
```

The problem doesn't exist with drawing lines:

```
public void Draw(Point location)
    {
        lineObject.X2 = location.X;
        lineObject.Y2 = location.Y;
    }
```

I know it's trivial, but I'm completely stuck on this. How should I handle drawing Ellipses?

Comment: Why not use Math.Abs to remove the negative?

Comment: This way Ellipse will grow in the opposite direction than i want it to instead of throwing exception. I need to achieve Paint like functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this EXACT problem when trying to create a crop tool. Problem is that you need to create if statements for when the cursor goes negative X or negative Y from your starting point. For starters, you'll need to have a global Point that you mark as your 'start' point. Also specify a global current point position that we'll talk about in a minute.

```
public Point startingPoint;
public Point currentPoint;
```

Then, make sure you have an onMouseDown event on whatever control you are trying to put the ellipse on.

```
private void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       startingPoint.X = e.X;
       startingPoint.Y = e.Y;
    }
```

Then, you need to create if statements in your MouseMove event to check with point (current mouse position, or starting point) has a lower X/Y value

```
private void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
          //The below point is what we'll draw the ellipse with.
          Point ellipsePoint;
          Ellipse ellipseObject = new Ellipse();
          currentPoint.X = e.X;
          currentPoint.Y = e.Y;
         //Then we need to get the proper width/height;
          if (currentPoint.X >= startingPoint.X)
          {
                 ellipsePoint.X = startingPoint.X;
                 ellipseObject.Width = currentPoint.X - startingPoint.X;
          }
          else
          {
                ellipsePoint.X = currentPoint.X;
                ellipseObject.Width = startingPoint.X - currentPoint.X;
          }
          if (currentPoint.Y >= startingPoint.Y)
          {
                ellipsePoint.Y = startingPoint.Y;
                ellipseObject.Height = currentPoint.Y - startingPoint.Y;
          }
          else
          {
                ellipsePoint.Y = currentPoint.Y;
                ellipseObject.Height = startingPoint.Y - currentPoint.Y;
          }
           ellipseObject.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
           ellipseObject.StrokeThickness = 2;
           ellipseObject.Margin = new Thickness(ellipsePoint.X, ellipsePoint.Y, 0, 0);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Save the origin point separately and set the X and Y properties of the Ellipse's Margin to the mouse position and the Width and Height to the distances between the mouse and origin point.

Untested:

```
public MyCircle(Point location)
{
    ellipseObject = new Ellipse
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
        StrokeThickness = 2,
        Margin = new Thickness(location.X, location.Y, 0, 0)
        Tag = new Point(location.X, location.Y)
    };
}

public void Draw(Point location)
{
    if (ellipseObject != null)
    {                
        Point o = (Point)ellipseObject.Tag;
        double x = Math.Min(location.X, o.Left);
        double y = Math.Min(location.Y, o.Top);
        double width = Math.Abs(Math.Max(location.X, o.Left) - x);
        double height = Math.Abs(Math.Max(location.Y, o.Top) - y);
        ellipseObject.Margin.X = x;
        ellipseObject.Margin.Y = y;
        ellipseObject.Width = width;
        ellipseObject.Height = height;               
    }
}
```